# why is this an infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop

I can't seem to figure out why this is an infinite loop in python??

```
for i in range(n):
    j=1
    while((i*j)<n):
       j+=1
```

shouldn't the outer loop go n times. incrementing j until its equal to n div i each time?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`i` starts at `0`, so the `while` condition stays always true; see the [range docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) for details.

Answer (score 16):

You can create a "trace" showing the state changes of the variables.

1. n= 5; i= 0
2. n= 5; i= 0; j= 1
3. i*j < n -> 0 < 5: n= 5; i= 0; j= 2
4. i*j < n -> 0 < 5: n= 5; i= 0; j= 3
5. i*j < n -> 0 < 5: n= 5; i= 0; j= 4
6. i*j < n -> 0 < 5: n= 5; i= 0; j= 5
7. i*j < n -> 0 < 5: n= 5; i= 0; j= 6

etc.

You can prove that your trace is correct by inserting `print` statements.

**When in doubt, print it out.**

Comment: and use the logging module in bigger programs. You need to modify just one line to change the verbosity

Answer (score 12):

`i` starts at zero, so the condition for the inner loop is always `0*j < n`, which will always be true.

Answer (score 7):

Because the initial value of `i` is 0.

Answer (score 4):

The first value in `i` will be 0. 0 times anything is 0.

Answer (score 2):

because i is 0!! and i*j=0

Answer (score 2):

`range(n)` starts at `0`, not `1`. `0 * j` will always be less than `n`.

Answer (score 1):

On the first time through the outer loop, the inner loop becomes an infinite loop.
It doesn't matter what happens after that.  There's no "after infinity".

Answer (score 0):

i is 0 rewrite you loop like

```
for i in range(1,n):
j=1
while((i*j)<n):
   j+=1
```

using this version of the range function will create a range that starts at 1 instead of 0